# Controlling the background color of a JTextField with a mouse clicked event

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, mouseclick-event

I'm currently working on a program of mine for personal development as a programmer and I have hit a miniature brick wall of frustration on this mouseclicked event I'm working on. When I thought up the procedure in my mind and on the white board I saw it utilizing a switch statement to get the job done. I have met with no success with this plan. I have since experimented with a few other control structures, but nothing seems to work the problem is controlling the control structure inside the mouseClicked event. I'll provide some relevant example code to try to communicate my objective. Note that I know the provided code is bad. I'm just trying to communicate an idea. 
The goal is to be able to have the box start out green, then the user can click the box turn it red, click again it goes white, and one last time it goes back to green. For some reason this is beyond me at the moment. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
        //This component allows the user to store information on current unit identifier. Maybe necessary to pass this in as an arguement to the PssGui since there is no accounting for callsigns. 
    //This component also needs to be updated with a mouse click event that can turn the color of the box to reflect the tooltip text.
    unitId = new JTextField();
    unitId.setEditable(false);
    unitId.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    unitId.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    unitId.setToolTipText("<html>SHADE CELLS TO REFLECT CURRENT UNIT STATUS:" + "<br/>GREEN-MC" + "<br/>RED-NMC" + "<br/>WHITE-UNIT IN TRANSISTION</html>");
    unitId.setText("A 4/5");
    unitId.setBounds(0, 116, 79, 172);
    getContentPane().add(unitId);
    unitId.setColumns(10);
    unitId.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            //Fill with sweet code to change the color of this box accordingly.
            //use an Int and a while loop or something so that every click increments the Int
            //then each int value corresponds to a color 
            // have a statement at the end that resets the int back to zero to keep the colors in the loop
            //I.E int color = 0, mouse click happens int color = 1, now color =1 which turns the box red, 
            //color can never be greater than 3, when it is, we set color back to zero. 

            for(int i = 0; i<=3; i++){
                switch (i){
                case 1: unitId.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                break;
                case 2: unitId.setBackground(Color.red);
                break;
                case 3: unitId.setBackground(Color.white);
                break;
                }
            }//end while



            //System.out.println(i);


        }
    });
```

Addendum:

I fixed my own problem. I knew it was going to be something trivial and I apologize if posting here was a waste of server resources. I was massively frustrated last night when I was trying to solve this problem. Here is the functional code. The lesson to remember here is to take a break and don't always try to force the solution.

```
unitId = new JTextField();
    unitId.setEditable(false);
    unitId.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    unitId.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    unitId.setToolTipText("<html>SHADE CELLS TO REFLECT CURRENT UNIT STATUS:" + "<br/>GREEN-MC" + "<br/>RED-NMC" + "<br/>WHITE-UNIT IN TRANSISTION</html>");
    unitId.setText("A 4/5");
    unitId.setBounds(0, 116, 79, 172);
    getContentPane().add(unitId);
    unitId.setColumns(10);
    unitId.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            //Fill with sweet code to change the color of this box accordingly.
            //use an Int and a while loop or something so that every click increments the Int
            //then each int value corresponds to a color 
            // have a statement at the end that resets the int back to zero to keep the colors in the loop
            //I.E int color = 0, mouse click happens int color = 1, now color =1 which turns the box red, 
            //color can never be greater than 3, when it is, we set color back to zero. 


            if(starter==0){
                unitId.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                starter++;
            }
            else if(starter==1){
                unitId.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                starter++;
            }
            else if(starter==2){
                unitId.setBackground(Color.RED);
                starter++;
            }
            else{
                starter=0;
                unitId.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

            }


            //System.out.println(i);


        }
    });
```

Comment: Upon further reflection, I think there maybe a possible solution in using an Array. I'm not 100% yet and won't be until I can try to write up and implement some code. I'm still interested in any suggestions or alternative solutions.

Comment: I fixed my own problem. I knew it was going to be something trivial and I apologize if posting here was a waste of server resources. I was massively frustrated last night when I was trying to solve this problem.